# How to mix $query->andFilterWhere and $query->query in Yii2 elasticsearch 6

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2, elasticsearch-6

I updated my yii2 system from yii2-elasticsearch 2.0 to 2.1 and elasticsearch package from 2.2.1 to 6.2.1. In the old system I could mix `$query->andFilterWhere` and `$query->query` as follows (the search method is in a class derived from `yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord`):

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = self::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'languageCode' => \Yii::$app->locale->languageCode,
    ]);

    $queryPart = [];
    if (!empty($this->term)) {
        $queryPart['filtered']['query']['multi_match'] = [
        // ES6: $queryPart['bool']['must']['multi_match'] = [
            'query' => $this->term,
            'operator' => 'and',
            'type' => $this->getQueryType($this->term),
            'fields' => [
                'name_*',
                'meta_description_*'
            ]
        ];
    }

    if (!empty($queryPart)) {
        $query->query($queryPart);
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

It worked with ES 2.2.1 without any problem, but now the `andFilterWhere` overwrites `$query->query` independently from the sequence. If one of the two parts is removed the other filter works perfectly, only together not.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You must use bool query and put all part of your query in one "query" object... 
Something like this:

```
query => [
      bool => [ 
          must => [
               multi_match => [
                        'query' => $this->term,
                        'operator' => 'and', 
                        'type' => $this->getQueryType($this->term), 
                        'fields' => [
                               'name_*', 
                               'meta_description_*'
                      ]
               ]
         ]
         filter => [
              'languageCode' => \Yii::$app->locale->languageCode
          ]
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: I know about a similar solution, but I don't want to loose the simplicity of the using of ActiveQuery andFilterWhere. The question is "How to mix?". That worked earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be bug, as confirmed by other users on [github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch/issues/171).